# String поиск индекса символа в строке

Tags: javascript, строки, index, indexof

подскажите пожалуйста добрые люди)
Есть ли возможность в строке "1==2==3=4==5===6=7" узнать индекс символа "=" пропустив при этом определенное число символов "="

Например, надо найти в этой же строке индекс символа "=", пропустив до этого 5 символов "=", т.е. ответ индекс=9
либо пропустив 2 символа "=", при этом индекс = 4

Comment: Да, есть возможность. Написать собственную функцию.

Comment: Дык считайте символы. Шестой - на нужном индексе.

Comment: Язык то программирования какой интересует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, необходимо добавить пару проверок, чтобы не "падало" в случае некорректных аргументов, но пока с поставленной задачей справляется:

```js
function fIndexOffset(sText, sSimbol, nSkip) {
  let arr = [];
  [...sText].forEach(function(simbol, i) {
    if (simbol === sSimbol) { arr.push(i); };
  });
  return arr[nSkip];
}

console.log(fIndexOffset('1==2==3=4==5===6=7', '=', 5));
console.log(fIndexOffset('1==2==3=4==5===6=7', '=', 2));
```